# How to stop Microsoft cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js to stop listening manually?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I've implemented a Speech to Text conversion using [Cognitive Services](https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js). I need it to stop listening after staying active for some specific time.

In C# version of the SDK, there is a method to make it stop listening as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer?view=azure-dotnet).
Sample - `// Stops recognition.
         await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

I was looking similar method in JavaScript sdk but couldn't find any. So is there any way to make it stop listening?

EDIT - Adding my code sample-

```
var recognizer = new scope.SDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(function (result) {
    console.log(result.text)
})
```

I need it to stop it even while it is listening to something.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for providing [this C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer?view=azure-dotnet).  The example there helped me a lot. Hopefully it will help some other users, as well. My upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync()` is the method you're looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechrecognizer?view=azure-node-latest#stopcontinuousrecognitionasync-------void---e--string-----void-